# Show a date variable from database - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an attribute in my user database of type "Date".
I want to show it in the "show view", in any format.
What shall I write in show.html.erb so that I can see the contents of this field of a user object ?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to store the date format in a config file and/or a helper so you can easily modify it and use it globally wherever you are printing it in a view.

You can print a date like this:

```
<%= @user.datecolumn.strftime('%B %d, %Y') %>
```

See this article where the date formats are listed and there is more information on the subject:

http://www.linux-mag.com/id/4070/

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. We are realising that we are not correctly writing the date to the "end_date" field of the record in the database. Hence we have a nil error. Our form field for the date is the following:
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :end_date %><br />
    <%= date_select("show", "end_date", :default => Date.today, :order => [:month, :day, :year], :start_year => Date.today.year, :end_year => Date.today.year + 10)%>
  </div>

Any comments on why this doesn't work ?

Comment: You appear to be using a form builder (because of the `f.label`).  So why is your date select not also tied to the form builder (i.e. `f.date_select` and without the model name)?  Secondly as with any updating problem you should check your server log and see what is submitted when you submit the form.  If that doesn't help, you may want to start a new question, as it is a different one than you asked.  And please accept my answer if it helped with your view question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= user.created_at.strftime("%B %m") %>
```

Take a look at the `strftime` method: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime